# (Oracle) Convert us7ascii in Snowflake?

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I'm looking for an alternative for the oracle convert() function in Snowflake. More specifically speaking I want to replace special characters in a string value (e.g. é, ä, ö) with the best matching letters.

In Oracle I can do something like this:
`convert('émíliõ', 'us7ascii')`
which would return 'emilio'.

I know I can write loads of replace() statements to do this but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the TRANSLATE function [Translate](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/translate.html#translate)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27559863)

Comment: Hi @Sabre - the answer was to use the TRANSLATE statement. The link was just to the TRANSLATE function documentation that shows how to use the function and was additional information rather than being the answer.

Comment: Well I think my generated review comment is clear enough. You can include an example and it will be a valid answer. Otherwise you could've posted a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

````
translate('émíliõ',

'ÄäÀàÁáÂâÃãÅåǍǎĄąĂăÆæĀā
ÇçĆćĈĉČč
ĎđĐďð
ÈèÉéÊêËëĚěĘęĖėĒē
ĜĝĢģĞğ
Ĥĥ
ÌìÍíÎîÏïıĪīĮį
Ĵĵ
Ķķ
ĹĺĻļŁłĽľĿŀ
ÑñŃńŇňŅņ
ÖöÒòÓóÔôÕõŐőØøŒœ
ŔŕŘř
ẞßŚśŜŝŞşŠšȘș
ŤťŢţÞþȚț
ÜüÙùÚúÛûŰűŨũŲųŮůŪū
Ŵŵ
ÝýŸÿŶŷ
ŹźŽžŻż',

'AaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAa
CcCcCcCc
DdDdo
EeEeEeEeEeEeEeEe
GgGgGg
Hh
IiIiIiIilIiIi
JJ
Kk
LlLlLlLlLl
NnNnNnNn
OoOoOoOoOoOoOooo
RrRr
ssSsSsSsSsSs
TtTtÞbTt
UuUuUuUuUuUuUuUuUu
Ww
YyYyYy
ZzZzZz')```

Thanks @NickW !
````

Comment: Yep, I think that's your best way if doing it. Nice one.

Comment: Hi @codie-fz  - if my answer helped then please could you tick it? thanks